# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt MVC5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Currently facing this issue in Visual studio:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Unknown Module.
>   Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt**

I do not have any code that I can show as I get this error when I start a new MVC 5 project. Facing the same issues if I try a regular MVC 4 project.
The projects builds just fine but when I try to run I get that error.

**Note I haven't added any code. It's just a plain MVC 5 project.**

Comment: You should reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: I've done that +trying to repair it.

Comment: What operating system, and do you have updates installed?

Comment: Windows 10. It did work flawless yesterday, but today this error just started to come up. Also it's just not for a mvc5 project. It's for every project, console. wpf etc. And also on Visual studio 2012 / 2015

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, in windows 10. My solution was Install Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 and still works.
You can download this package here https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=519379.